# Exchange Syncing Wrong Account

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, sync, exchange, office365

My org is in the middle of a hybrid Office 365 deployment where we plan to first implement Office desktop apps, and then move forward with Exchange separately. In our test environment, we have 7 user accounts, and all have worked well, with one exception: Exchange email.

I should clarify the actual issue. We are connecting to 365 email rather than on-premise Exchange.

After some extensive troubleshooting, we have come to the conclusion that we have two Autodiscover records in our AD database. Under AD Sites and Services, we have an SCP record for our on-prem Exchange server (under MEx - (company) - Admin Groups - Ex Admin Group - Servers - (server name) - Protocols - Autodiscover). This record, we want to keep until we go live with Office 365 Exchange. The other record is located under MEx Autodiscover - MEx Online.

I'm not an AD guru by any means, so these may be elementary questions, but, if I delete the second record, will this fix our issue? If not, what's the solution here? And if we delete the record, will this affect things when we finally go live with Office 365 Exchange?

Answer (score 1):

We actually found a fix today that involves the registry. Inserting the following key did the trick:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\outlook\autodiscover
>   DWORD: ExcludeExplicitO365Endpoint Value = 1

See [here](https://www.gothamweb.com/portal/index.php/knowledgebase/8/Outlook-bypasses-AutoDiscover-and-connects-directly-to-Office-365-mailbox.html)